# ASP.NET MVC CORS issue

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC application (.NET 4.6) where on one occasion I need to redirect to a different domain.

So the code is like this (only authenticated users can come to the controller):

```
public ActionResult UploadForDesign(int parcelId)
{
  ......
  string url = "differentdomain/parcelId" ; 
  return ReDirect(url); 
}
```

I am getting an error:

> has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'.....
>
> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED

I did the following in the control before redirect call

```
HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

and I still get the same error.

Also I tried the following in web.config, but didn't help much.

```
<httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <clear />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
      </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Now I had another test bare ASP.NET MVC app (.NET 4.5.2) with no authentication, and the above code works fine. I checked all the code and it looks the same except authentication in place and the framework version.

Any idea what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use the WithOrigins method on your CORS policy and add whatever domain you need:

```
services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                builder =>
                .WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200/")
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowCredentials()
                );
        });
```

Ahhh sorry. I believe you should be able to use something like:

```
var p = new CorsPolicy();
p.AllowAnyHeader = true;
p.AllowAnyMethod = true;
p.AllowAnyOrigin = false;
p.Origins.Add("http://localhost:4200/");
```

Comment: I am not using .Core. I am using .net platform...is there any equivalent?